# SQL Server BCP command

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp

I am putting together a `bcp` command to output a file at the end of a stored procedure.

If I run the code shown below and then select the contents of the variable and append `EXEC xp_cmdshell` to the beginning, it works fine.

If I run it all the way through i.e. `EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd`, I am getting an error

> 'bcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command

I can't see where my code is wrong, can anyone see the issue please?

```
DECLARE @PeriodStamp VARCHAR(8000) = REPLACE(CAST(GETDATE() - 2 AS DATE), '-', '')

DECLARE @marketingoptinp1 VARCHAR(8000) = '''bcp "select ''''Created_DateTime'''', ''''Application_Date'''', ''''Application_ID'''', ''''Customer_ID'''', ''''First_Name'''', ''''Last_Name'''', ''''Email'''', ''''Mobile_Phone'''', ''''Home_Phone'''', ''''Gender'''', ''''DOB'''', ''''AGE'''',  ''''Marital_Status_ID'''', ''''Marital_Status_Desc'''', ''''Dependent_Number'''', ''''Dependent_Number_Desc'''', ''''Employment_Industry_ID'''', ''''Employment_Industry_Desc'''', ''''Income_Source_ID'''', ''''Income_Source_Desc'''', ''''Loan_Amount'''', ''''Loan_Purpose_ID'''', ''''Loan_Purpose_Desc'''', ''''Residence_Type_ID'''', ''''Residence_Type_Desc'''', ''''Postcode'''', ''''Address1'''', ''''Address2'''', ''''City'''', ''''County'''', ''''Marketing_Opt_In'''', ''''IP_Address'''', ''''Bank_Sort_Code'''', ''''Device'''', ''''Lender_Result'''', ''''Rental_Mortgage_Payments'''', ''''Has_Pension'''', ''''PeriodStamp'''' union all SELECT Created_DateTime, cast(Application_Date as nvarchar(10)) as Application_Date, cast(Application_ID as nvarchar(15)) as Application_ID, cast(Customer_ID as nvarchar(15)) as Customer_ID , cast(First_Name as varchar(150)) as First_Name , cast(Last_Name as varchar(150)) as Last_Name , cast(Email as varchar(250)) as Email , quintegrity.[dbo].[udf_AlphaNumericElement](Mobile_Phone,4) as Mobile_Phone , quintegrity.[dbo].[udf_AlphaNumericElement](Home_Phone,4) as Home_Phone , Gender, cast(DOB as nvarchar(15)) as DOB, cast(AGE as nvarchar(3)) as AGE, cast(Marital_Status_ID as nvarchar(2)) as Marital_Status_ID, Marital_Status_Desc,  cast(Dependent_Number as nvarchar(20)) as Dependent_Number, Dependent_Number_Desc, cast(Employment_Industry_ID as nvarchar(10)) as Employment_Industry_ID, Employment_Industry_Desc, cast(Income_Source_ID as nvarchar(10)), Income_Source_Desc, cast(Loan_Amount as nvarchar(20)) as Loan_Amount, cast(Loan_Purpose_ID as nvarchar(6)) as Loan_Purpose_ID, Loan_Purpose_Desc,  cast(Residence_Type_ID as nvarchar(6)) as Residence_Type_ID, Residence_Type_Desc , cast(Postcode as varchar(150)) Postcode  , cast(Address1 as varchar(150)) Address1 , cast(Address2 as varchar(150)) Address2 , cast(City as varchar(150)) City , cast(County as varchar(150)) County , cast(Marketing_Opt_In as nvarchar(2)) as Marketing_Opt_In,  cast(IP_Address as nvarchar(20)) as IP_Address, cast(Bank_Sort_Code as nvarchar(10)) as Bank_Sort_Code, Device, Lender_Result, cast(Rental_Mortgage_Payments as nvarchar(15)) as Rental_Mortgage_Payments, Has_Pension, PeriodStamp FROM scratch.dbo.data_extract where Marketing_Opt_In = 1 and PeriodStamp = ' + @PeriodStamp 

DECLARE @marketingoptinp2 VARCHAR(8000) 
SET @marketingoptinp2 = ' " queryout "C:\test\data' + @PeriodStamp+'.txt" -T -c'''

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(8000)
SET @cmd = @marketingoptinp1 + @marketingoptinp2

EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Comment: Good. bcp is a command line tool. Execute it from the *command line*, dont' break security just to allow the *server* to run a script. If you want to run this periodically, or even once, in a while create a SQL Server Agent job

Comment: If you want to *export* data, use SSIS or actually create a proper report with Reporting Services. What you do is wrong on many levels - you had to disable security features in order to run `xp_cmdshell`, you allow SQL injection attacks by concatenating strings, you allow such attacks to execute arbitrary commands using SQL Server's account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string passed through a variable need not be double quoted in way you did, 
it should be like this:

```
DECLARE @marketingoptinp1 VARCHAR(8000) = 'bcp "select Created_DateTime, Application_Date, Application_ID, Customer_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Mobile_Phone, Home_Phone, Gender, DOB, AGE,  Marital_Status_ID, Marital_Status_Desc, Dependent_Number, Dependent_Number_Desc, Employment_Industry_ID, Employment_Industry_Desc, Income_Source_ID, Income_Source_Desc, Loan_Amount, Loan_Purpose_ID, Loan_Purpose_Desc, Residence_Type_ID, Residence_Type_Desc, Postcode, Address1, Address2, City, County, Marketing_Opt_In, IP_Address, Bank_Sort_Code, Device, Lender_Result, Rental_Mortgage_Payments, Has_Pension, PeriodStamp union all SELECT Created_DateTime, cast(Application_Date as nvarchar(10)) as Application_Date, cast(Application_ID as nvarchar(15)) as Application_ID, cast(Customer_ID as nvarchar(15)) as Customer_ID , cast(First_Name as varchar(150)) as First_Name , cast(Last_Name as varchar(150)) as Last_Name , cast(Email as varchar(250)) as Email , quintegrity.[dbo].[udf_AlphaNumericElement](Mobile_Phone,4) as Mobile_Phone , quintegrity.[dbo].[udf_AlphaNumericElement](Home_Phone,4) as Home_Phone , Gender, cast(DOB as nvarchar(15)) as DOB, cast(AGE as nvarchar(3)) as AGE, cast(Marital_Status_ID as nvarchar(2)) as Marital_Status_ID, Marital_Status_Desc,  cast(Dependent_Number as nvarchar(20)) as Dependent_Number, Dependent_Number_Desc, cast(Employment_Industry_ID as nvarchar(10)) as Employment_Industry_ID, Employment_Industry_Desc, cast(Income_Source_ID as nvarchar(10)), Income_Source_Desc, cast(Loan_Amount as nvarchar(20)) as Loan_Amount, cast(Loan_Purpose_ID as nvarchar(6)) as Loan_Purpose_ID, Loan_Purpose_Desc,  cast(Residence_Type_ID as nvarchar(6)) as Residence_Type_ID, Residence_Type_Desc , cast(Postcode as varchar(150)) Postcode  , cast(Address1 as varchar(150)) Address1 , cast(Address2 as varchar(150)) Address2 , cast(City as varchar(150)) City , cast(County as varchar(150)) County , cast(Marketing_Opt_In as nvarchar(2)) as Marketing_Opt_In,  cast(IP_Address as nvarchar(20)) as IP_Address, cast(Bank_Sort_Code as nvarchar(10)) as Bank_Sort_Code, Device, Lender_Result, cast(Rental_Mortgage_Payments as nvarchar(15)) as Rental_Mortgage_Payments, Has_Pension, PeriodStamp FROM scratch.dbo.data_extract where Marketing_Opt_In = 1 and PeriodStamp = ' + @PeriodStamp
```

The same thing in your second variable, you should delete two ending quotes:

```
DECLARE @marketingoptinp2 VARCHAR(8000) 
SET @marketingoptinp2 = ' " queryout "C:\test\data' + @PeriodStamp+'.txt" -T -c'
```

Comment: Hi sepupic, thanks for the reply, I have done as you suggested but when I run the output I get the error bcp: unknown option '

Comment: @PJD That is because in your second variable there is another double quote, I noted it only now, please see my updated answer